# change color of only one bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I want to color only one bar in ggplot. This is my data frame:

```
area <- c("Północ", "Południe", "Wschód", "Zachód")
sale <- c(16.5, 13.5, 14, 13)
df.sale <- data.frame(area, sale)
colnames(df.sale) <- c("Obszar sprzedaży", "Liczba sprzedanych produktów (w tys.)")
```

And code for plotting:

```
plot.sale.bad <- ggplot(data=df.sale, aes(x=area, y=sale, fill=area)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "red", "black", "black")) +
  xlab(colnames(df.sale)[1]) +
  ylab(colnames(df.sale)[2]) +
  ggtitle("Porównanie sprzedaży")
```

I would like to have only one bar colored and 3 others to have default color (darkgrey, not black, it looks bad for me). How can I change color of only on bar or how to get name of the default color of bars to put them instead of black?

Comment: If you don't want to map `fill` to 'area', why do you use it in your `aes`? It might be better to add a variable to your data frame that reflects the conditions you wish map to `fill`. But you need to describe your objectives more clearly.

Comment: I want to distinguish second bar form others by color and other bars should have default, unchanged color. That's what I want.

Comment: For the example you've provided, `scale_fill_manual` is spot on. If you want to do it more "programmatically" then you'll need to provide some indicator (calculation, `cut` range, etc) that would make it possible to determine which bar(s) should be a different color. For your example, what condition indicated that `Południe` should be red?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Option 1: Change color of only one bar. Following Henrick's suggestion, you can create a new variable with NAs for the default color and character strings/factors for non-default colors (the first one happens to be red):

```
area.color <- c(NA, "withcolor", NA, NA)
plot.sale.bad <- ggplot(data=df.sale, aes(x=area, y=sale, fill=area.color)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab(colnames(df.sale)[1]) +
  ylab(colnames(df.sale)[2]) +
  ggtitle("Porównanie sprzedaży") 
plot.sale.bad
```

Option 2: Find the name of the default dark gray color you like. This is not the default color if you simply remove the `scale_fill_manual` line in your original code (in that case, you get four different pastels), so I assume you mean the grey color produced by the code chunk just above this paragraph, for those bars where `area.color==NA`. In that case, you might look at the source code (or args, anyway) for `scale_fill_discrete`:

```
> args(scale_fill_discrete)
# function (..., h = c(0, 360) + 15, c = 100, l = 65, h.start = 0, 
#     direction = 1, na.value = "grey50") 
# NULL
```

The default for `na.value` is `"grey50"`. So if you wanted to use `scale_fill_manual`, you could do it like so:

```
plot.sale.bad <- ggplot(data=df.sale, aes(x=area, y=sale, fill=area)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey50", "red", "grey50", "grey50")) +
  xlab(colnames(df.sale)[1]) +
  ylab(colnames(df.sale)[2]) +
  ggtitle("Porównanie sprzedaży") 
plot.sale.bad
```

Comment: Just a small update, as the `area.colour <- c(NA, "withcolor", NA, NA)` did not work for me (bars 1, 3 and 4 were simply missing). Instead, I used `area.colour <- c("one", "two", "one", "one")` and then `scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray50", "red"))`, which worked like a charm (and you can easily control legend labels with whatever is in `area.colour`).

Answer (score 39):

If you like having everything in the ggplot call, you can use an `ifelse` statement within `factor()` for the fill as shown below.

This also separates the legend into two categories (i.e. highlighted and not highlighted) so that you aren't repeating the values shown on the x axis. This also provides another illustrative dimension to the plot in the legend.

```
plot.sale.bad2 <- ggplot(data=df.sale,
                         aes(x=area,
                             y=sale,
                             fill=factor(ifelse(area=="Południe","Highlighted","Normal")))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "area", values=c("red","grey50")) +
  xlab(colnames(df.sale)[1]) +
  ylab(colnames(df.sale)[2]) +
  ggtitle("Porównanie sprzedaży") 

plot.sale.bad2
```

[image: Plot with legend]

If the legend isn't needed you can add `show.legend = FALSE` to the `geom_bar()` call to produce the following:

[image: Plot without legend]

Comment: This is precious.