# Using a different color for only the selected bar in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to highlight the bar in the middle (named SSA) using a different color. I have tried the available examples, but not getting the desired result.

It seems I'm not being able to use the `ifelse` element correctly. Thanks for helping to detect the error.

"fill" is not a factor in my data, unlike in the solution provided here: [change color of only one bar in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894102/change-color-of-only-one-bar-in-ggplot)

Data:

```
structure(list(yield = c(48, 33, 46, 44, 79, 20, 21, 8, 40, 72, 
12, 31, 65, 10, 71, 36, 20, 60, 69, 59, 58, 49, 75, 28, 71, 61, 
34, 39, 42, 64, 47, 36, 78, 73, 51, 46, 3, 55, 70, 80, 29, 45, 
70, 72, 32, 42, 48), df = c(2, 13, 0, 9, -3, 3, 2, 0, 2, 11, 
0, 0, 5, -2, -1, -15, 0, 2, 14, 1, 6, 2, -1, 2, 8, 16, 8, 0, 
-13, 3, 0, 10, 10, -3, 7, 0, -6, 16, 0, 1, -23, 9, 11, 12, 4, 
8, 28), country = c("Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", 
"Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cameroon", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Comoros", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", "Congo, Rep.", "Cote d'Ivoire", 
"Equatorial Guinea", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia, The", 
"Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Liberia", 
"Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mozambique", 
"Namibia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
"Sudan", "Tanzania", "Togo", "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe", 
"SSA")), row.names = c(NA, -47L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

My code:

```
ggplot(arble.land, 
       aes(x = reorder(country, yield), y = yield), 
       col = ifelse(country = "SSA", "Highlighted", "Normal")) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Try moving the `col = ifelse(...)` portion *inside* `aes()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change color of only one bar in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894102/change-color-of-only-one-bar-in-ggplot)

Comment: The 'fill' option is not a 'factor' in my data which made it look different to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

- as @Z_Lin mentions, the color part should be in the call to `aes`.
- in the `if_else` statement you should use a logical operator like `==`
- the `col` argument affects the line color of the bar, you might have preferred the `fill` argument

The following code:

```
ggplot(arble.land, 
       aes(x = reorder(country, yield), 
           y = yield, 
           fill = ifelse(country == "SSA", "Highlighted", "Normal") )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  ## drop legend and Y-axis title
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_flip()
```

yields this graph:

[image]

please let me know whether this is what you want.

### Update

if you want to remove "extra space" on the left and right, you may use the `expand` argument in `coord_flip` like this

```
ggplot(arble.land, 
       aes(x = reorder(country, yield), 
           y = yield, 
           fill = ifelse(country == "SSA", "Highlighted", "Normal") )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  ## drop legend and Y-axis title
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_flip(expand = FALSE) ########## SMALL UPDATE
```

yielding the following plot:

[image]

### Update 2: Fill colors

You can set the colors manually with `scale_fill_manual()`

```
ggplot(arble.land, 
       aes(x = reorder(country, yield), 
           y = yield, 
           fill = ifelse(country == "SSA", "Highlighted", "Normal") )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  ## add manual color scale
  scale_fill_manual("legend",         ###### in this call: colour change
                    values = c("Highlighted" = "black", "Normal" = "orange")) +
  ## drop legend and Y-axis title
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_flip(expand = FALSE)
```

producing this plot:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much for the solution. One additional question if you don't mind, is it possible to remove the gray space between the country names and the bars on the left?

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit The answers to this question should solve that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2/52318834#52318834

Comment: Does this method allow changing bar colors?

Comment: @divibisan Its showing an error like continuous scale used as factor.

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit adding an argument to coord_flip allows for this: `coord_flip(expand = FALSE) `. I will update the answer.

Comment: Any answer regarding the colors of the bar?

Comment: @Julien I will post an update with code that changes the color of the bar in a few minutes.