# Color sample in ggplot dds analysis

Tags: r, plot

I've generated this PCA using this code

```
percentVar <- round(100 * attr(pca_data, "percentVar"))
ggplot(pca_data, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = condition, shape = treatment, label = name)) +
geom_point(size = 2) +
geom_text() +
xlab(paste0("PC1: ",percentVar[1],"% variance")) +
ylab(paste0("PC2: ",percentVar[2],"% variance"))
```

[image]

And following further analysis

```
as_tibble(counts(dds1[res_tbl_1$ENSEMBL[1:2], ], normalize = TRUE),
rownames = 'ENSEMBL') %>%
pivot_longer(names_to = "sample", values_to = "counts", -ENSEMBL) %>%
left_join(as_tibble(colData(dds1))) %>%
mutate(name = paste0(treatment, '_', condition, '_', 1:12)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = name, y = counts, fill = condition)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = "gray30") +
facet_wrap( ~ ENSEMBL, scales = "free") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 90),
axis.title.x = element_blank(),
legend.position = "right",
legend.text = element_text(size = 7),
legend.title = element_text(size = 7))
```

I have generated this image
[image]

Seeing the PCA analysis, it looks like sample 6 might be an outlier, I'd like to color it on the second image soo it stands out but I don't know how

Comment: I think using `ifelse` as explained in a previous question may do the job: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103496/using-a-different-color-for-only-the-selected-bar-in-geom-bar. Cheers!